# flareget installation problem

Tags: apt

whenever I run, `sudo apt-get update`, I find
one is  :

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
in i386 packages of ppa                                
and 2nd : W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/flareget-i386/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I think there is problem in installation of flareget software
is there any command to fix this

Comment: I don't think that PPA has any software for saucy (Ubuntu 13.10). I just checked the URL path and when you get to here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/flareget-i386/ubuntu/dists/ There is not a directory for saucy.

Answer (score 0):

The PPA you added to install Flareget does not have any software for Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy).

You will have to the the Flareget software somewhere else.

First, lets remove the PPA so that apt can work without errors.

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/flareget-i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, download the .deb installer for Flareget from here: http://flareget.com/download

Double click on the .deb file you download and Ubuntu Software Center will install it for you.